# Discord detecting click with JavaScript in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, discord, undetected-chromedriver

I wrote code to retrieve a cookie from the website after logging in with a Discord token.

```
import os
import ctypes
import time
from pathlib import Path
from sys import platform
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import json
import argparse
import multiprocessing
import fade
import subprocess
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import requests
import cv2

# Read tokens from tokens.txt file
with open('tokens.txt', 'r') as file:
    tokens = file.read().splitlines()

# Create a new_cookies list to store the cookies
new_cookies = []

# Loop through each token
for i, token in enumerate(tokens, start=1):
    options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--single-process')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

    driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)

    try:
        # Open Discord login page
        driver.get("https://discord.com/login")

        # Inject token using JavaScript
        script = f"""
            const token = "{token}";
            setInterval(() => {{
                document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe')).contentWindow.localStorage.token = `"${{token}}"`;
            }}, 50);
            setTimeout(() => {{
                location.reload();
            }}, 2500);
        """
        driver.execute_script(script)

        # Wait for the page to load
        time.sleep(5)

        # Change the URL in the same tab
        driver.get("https://top.gg/bot/646937666251915264/vote?")

        # Wait for the new page to load
        time.sleep(6)

        # Find the "Log In" button element by CSS selector
        button_login = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.chakra-link.chakra-button.css-32nqj8"))
        )

        # Click the "Log In" button
        button_login.click()

        print("[+] Successfully clicked the Log In button.")

        # Wait for 20 seconds
        time.sleep(5)

        # Find the "Authorize" button element by CSS selector and click it using JavaScript
        try:
            button_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.contents-3NembX'))
            )
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button_element)
            print("[+] Successfully clicked the 'Authorize' button using JavaScript.")
        except TimeoutException:
            print("[-] 'Authorize' button not found on the screen.")

        # Wait for 10 seconds
        time.sleep(4)

        # Copy the 'connect.sid' cookie value
        cookie_value = driver.get_cookie('connect.sid')['value']

        # Find the desired button element by CSS selector
        button_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.chakra-avatar[data-testid]'))
        )

        # Get the data-testid value from the button element
        username = button_element.get_attribute("data-testid")

        # Create a cookie dictionary
        cookie = {
            "name": "connect.sid",
            "value": cookie_value,
            "domain": "top.gg",
            "path": "/",
            "username": username
        }

        # Append the cookie to the new_cookies list
        new_cookies.append(cookie)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"[-] Error encountered for token {token}: {str(e)}")
    finally:
        # Close the Chrome WebDriver
        driver.quit()

# Save the cookies in the new_cookies.txt file
with open('new_cookies.txt', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(new_cookies, file, indent=2)
time.sleep(2)
print("[+] Cookies saved in 'new_cookies.txt'.")
```

This is my code but when I run this, in the step of clicking authorise button, the website detects the click using JavaScript and actionchains. But when I use PyAutoGUI, it works.

How do I bypass this detection?
How do I make it so that clicking button with actionchains or Javascript won't get detected?